# .NET Core app looks for embedded file in the wrong folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core app that runs on .NET 4.5.2.

The app uses a file `hello.json`. I originally copied it to the build folder, like this:

```
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "copyToOutput": [ "hello.json" ]
  },
```

The file was then copied to `...\bin\Debug\net452\win7-x64\` during compilation.

I have no problem running MyApp.exe, but if I go to `...\bin\Debug\net452\` and run `win7-x64\MyApp.exe`, I get the following error when trying to read the file:
`System.IO.FileNotFoundException Could not find file '...\bin\Debug\net452\hello.json'.`

I tried to embed `hello.json` in the assembly, like this:

```
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "embed": [ "hello.json" ]
  }
```

but I got the same result.

How to make the app understand that it's supposed to look for the file where the `.exe` is, not where it's being run?

Comment: Can you show us the code which reads the file from disk?

Comment: It's just `using (var reader = new StreamReader(jsonFilePath, Encoding.UTF8)) { return reader.ReadToEnd(); }` with jsonFilePath the path relative to the .exe. I realized that embedding the file requires to change that (my example still worked but it was because I hadn't removed hello.json from the folder), I'm working on that atm. As an alternate solution I can find the executable path with `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)` but it looks dirty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I was getting the same result with the embedded resource because `hello.json` was still in the `win7-x64\` folder (it had been copied there by my previous compile).

You need to get this file from the assembly, so I changed this:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("hello.json", Encoding.UTF8))
{
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

to this:

```
Assembly executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Stream jsonStream = executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyApp.hello.json");
using (var reader = new StreamReader(jsonStream, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Reference: 
http://codeopinion.com/asp-net-core-embedded-resource/
(Note: it uses `resource` in JSON, which is now deprecated and should be replaced with `embed` - see my `project.json` in the question)

Comment: I am a bit curious how you managed to make this work. `GetExecutingAssembly()` is not available in .net core, so far as I can see.

Comment: @melwil  It's in `System.Reflection.Assembly. To be more precise I am using ASP.NET Core on .NET 4.5.2, ie not the .NET Core architecture

Comment: Ok, I reread the question now and saw that it was running on 4.5.2. Makes sense, then.

Answer (score 0):

you should give your json file a build action of "Content" and don't copy it to the output folder manually